# Getting "Error: you must authenticate to access this jenkins" when trying to run "Java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 /help"

Tags: jenkins

Getting below error

`Error: you must authenticate to access this jenkins" when trying to run "Java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 /help`

Steps performed as below,
1. Copied jenkins-cls.jar to the local drive.
2. Opened command prompt and navigate to path where jenkins-cls.jar is saved.
3. Type "Java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 /help" and press enter.

It should ask for pass-code but instead, it displayed message "Error: you must authenticate to access this jenkins".

Any help to resolve this query is highly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you might be hitting this issue:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18114. Check in the "configure global security" page that you have "TCP port for JNLP agents" set to fixed or random

Answer (score 20):

Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security ->

1. Enable Security Checked
2. Authorization -> Logged-in Users can do anything -> Checked allow anonymous 
   read access

Restart Jenkins and try running

`java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 help --username user --password pwd`

or

`java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 login -auth username:(password/token)`.

Answer (score 4):

The file name is now changed from `jenkins-cls.jar` to `jenkins-cli.jar`.

Make sure the user is registered in jenkins front-end and Enable Security is checked for the user.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -auth username:password
```

Comment: sudo java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth USERID:YOURPASSWORD help works well for me

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass your username and password while executing the command like as below:

`java -jar jenkins-cls.jar -s http://localhost:8080 /help --username <userName> --password <password>`

Comment: I am getting ERROR: "--username" is not a valid option

Answer (score 0):

Go into **Configure global security** section, search for **Allow anonymous read access**, check it as true, apply and save.

Or you can just choose **Anyone can do anything** instead of **Logged-in users can do anything**

Test your command now, it should be work